# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid query

Tags: angular, angular9

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'date' and 'mediator'
FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'date' and 'mediator'

Más que una pregunta es una aportación que quiero hacer y si pueden alguna retroalimentación ya que me encuentro en mi etapa de formación.

Me salio este error donde me dice que me dice que no estoy usando los filtros validos como son <, <=, >, or >= para la consulta que quiero armar, quiero comparar un string para que este no sea tomado en cuenta.

```
public getIncomesFilterMDD( dateStar: Date, dateEnd: Date, mediator?: string ): Observable<any[]> {
return this.firestore.collection<IncomeInterface>('incomes', ref => ref.
            where('date', '>=', dateStar).
            where('date', '<=', dateEnd).
            where('mediator', '<', mediator).
            where('mediator', '>', mediator)
        ).valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo un poco la documentación:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries?hl=es

Vi que es posible, 
Usa el operador 'in' para combinar hasta 10 cláusulas de igualdad (==) en el mismo campo con un OR lógico. Una consulta 'in' muestra documentos en los que el campo dado coincide con cualquiera de los valores de comparación.

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
return this.firestore.collection<IncomeInterface>('incomes', ref => ref.
            where('date', '>=', dateStar).
            where('date', '<=', dateEnd).
            where('mediator', 'in', ['Directos', 'Cuartos'])
        ).valueChanges();
```